# How does the Kirchhoff`s current law differ from the conservation of mass equation?

Tags: mass, conservation-laws

Both of them only and merely say that the inflows around a point equal to the outflows from that point. What is the difference then?

Comment: They are two completely different things. What do you mean by differ?

Comment: For a hydraulics network, for instance, they state the same thing.

Comment: The Kirchhoff's law is for electric currents & conservation of mass is for mass. The Kirchhoff's law talks about the flow of charges but flow of mass does not make much sense without context.

Comment: They are analogous concepts.  They obviously don't state the exact same thing; but you can interpret them in the same way.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_network_analysis Also refer to the "Deterministic network analysis" condition 1.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you expect to get as an answer to this beyond what was already said.  You can model hydraulic circuits as electrical circuits (for some conditions) and therefore can solve some problems using the same techniques.  The differences are simple.  One is for fluids, the other is for electricity.

Comment: If the other is only for the electricity, it would make more sense to refer to the mass conservation in the hydraulics problems.

Comment: The Kirchhoff law is about the conservation of the charges.

The conservation of mass is about the conservation of the masses.

Any conserving quantity has very similar formulas. I think it is a good question, but it is too simple for an ordinary answer.

Comment: @matlabcrz Hydraulics problems _do_ refer to mass conservation.   It just so happens that in some hydraulic networks it's possible to think of the analogy of an electrical circuit, where mass conservation applies the same way as Kirchoffs Laws apply to some electrical circuits.  No one said they are the exact same; but they behave the same in the problems where they are applicable.

Comment: I have seen mass referred to as mass charge. Also seen terms like carrier. Think its the same math applied to different kinds of content moving around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kirchoff Current Law can be stated as:
$$
I=\int_{s}\mathbf{i}\cdot \mathbf{ds}=0
$$

While the Mass Conservation can be stated as:
$$
Q=\int_{s}\mathbf{q}\cdot \mathbf{ds}=0
$$

In both cases, the integral, which is normally expressed as a simple sum, equals the total flux of current|caudal outside a certain closed control surface called "node". In this regard, both laws are equivalent under the given variable.

Note that a rotational current|caudal tangential to the surface $s$ will leads to no flux, hence the vectorial dot calculation is required.

Also note, that both "laws" are particular cases. As you clearly can note, these expressions must be corrected in order to include accumulation of charge|mass $q$|$m$, such in a capacitor|tank, introducing a time derivative of the total charge|mass inside the control surface.